# MongoDb how to count fields

Tags: mongodb

I have some data like this:

```
{
    user_id:1,
    group_id:123,
    discription:null
},
{
    user_id:1,
    group_id:321,
    discription:null
},
{
    user_id:1,
    group_id:123,
    discription:"text"
},
{
    user_id:1,
    group_id:321,
    discription:"another text"
},
{
    user_id:1,
    group_id:321,
    discription:"another another text"
},
etc..
```

I want get all groups (group by group_id), count of document in each group, and count of documents in that group that have "discription" with null value and not null value.
So i need results like:

```
[
    [group_id:123, count:2, isNull:1, isNotNull:1],
    [group_id:321, count:3, isNull:1, isNotNull:2]
]
```

I know how to group fields by "group_id" and get the "count", but I don't know how to get the info about "description".

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    {
        $match:{
            user_id:1
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id:'$group_id',
            group_id:{$first:'$group_id'},
            count:{'$sum':1}
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this Query

```
db.testing.aggregate([{
        $match:{
            user_id:1
        }
    },     
    {$project:{_id:0,user_id:1,group_id: 1,description: { $ifNull: [ "$discription", 1 ] }}},
    {
        $group:{
            _id:'$group_id',            
            group_count:{'$sum':1},
            IsNull:{"$sum":"$description"}
        }
    },
    {$project:{_id:0,group_id:"$_id", count:"$group_count", isNull:"$IsNull", isNotNull:{ $subtract:["$group_count","$IsNull"]}}}
])
```

Comment: This query is good if we know which fields exactly will be presented...